# CanCan::NotImplemented (This model adapter does not support fetching records from the database.):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, cancancan, ruby-2.7

After updating the ruby on rails application from ruby 2.5.1 & Rails 5.2.3 to ruby 2.7.3 & Rails 6.0.1

getting this error:

> CanCan::NotImplemented (This model adapter does not support fetching
> records from the database.):

Please suggest How to debug the application further.

Answer (score 1):

Update gem resolved the issue:

```
# gem 'cancancan', '2.3.0'  ## update version
gem 'cancancan', '~> 3.3.0'
```